# Images not showing when uploaded to server

Tags: html, image, ftp, server-side

I have a small five page website and have the images used across the website in the same folder, img. The website works fine offline and I upload everything with the same structure, however when I view the website on the server, certain images don't display for some reason.

For example, my logo and image slider photo's appear, but then images in the gallery are broken. They're all linked correctly, eg:

```
 <img src="img/logo.png">
```

They're all name appropriately too, such as slider_1.png etc.

I'm not sure why some display fine whilst others don't, despite them all being in the same folder and  being linked the same way in HTML.

Ok, the images are now working but for some reason the CSS isn't working correctly on my own server space, but works on my schools. I haven't played with any of the server settings etc.

Comment: Could you please share LIVE url?

Comment: are you sure that images which you are using does not have diff case in name? because linux servers are case sensitive.

Comment: Nope they're all lower case. Just testing a few things so will post the link in a few minutes, thanks.

Comment: well it is showing `404` that means images are not there, or you might have some rewrite rule written. Do post content of `.htaccess` if any and snap of the content of `img` directory

Comment: I'm not too sure what .htaccess is, I'll have a look. Here are some screenshots, one of the structure of the website http://i61.tinypic.com/105s3l1.png & then one of the images which aren't loading http://i59.tinypic.com/20g0crd.png. All of the full_1.jpg etc don't load.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS not displaying server-side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687978/css-not-displaying-server-side)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and after reading half of Google saw that the new version of FileZilla changed the image extensions from .jpg to .JPG when uploaded to the we- problem solved.

Answer (score -2):

You can change the code like this:

```
<img src="yourdomain.com/img/logo.png"=
```

Comment: Just tried but this isn't working. Even when I try to access the image directly online it comes up with 404 not found despite it being uploaded 100%!

Comment: Maybe the image is not at that name (for example, you write logo.png, instead of logo1.png). Or maybe is a problem with the server.

Comment: Nope, checked and they're all named correctly. I even batch renamed the gallery images which don't work to make them super simple. Such as gallery1.png, gallery2.png and so on and updated the img src to make sure I hadn't made any mistakes.